# Can a DocuSign Recipient have multiple types in one envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I was wondering if it's possible to have the same recipient be added more than once to an envelope representing different types.  For example I would like to add recipient A as both an Editor and Signer to the same outbound envelope.  The reason why I'm asking is that in this envelope, I may have recipient A be an editor for one document but a signer on another (where the envelope contains two documents).  Is this scenario even allowable with Docusign?  If so I can't seem to specify this through the DocuSign api, i.e. there is no DocumentId field for any of the envelope recipient types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine. You would need to add them twice in different roles in the routing order.

So, the first role would be the signer and have tags placed as appropriate.
Then add them again as an Editor so they can perform that role.

Comment: So say they should be a signer for document #1 and an Editor for document #2.  How do you specify in the Editor documentId = 2?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the scenario you've described is achievable in DocuSign. A recipient who's assigned the `Editor` role can basically do all the same things to the Envelope as the sender can do (i.e., add/update/remove recipients, add/update/remove tags, etc.). It's not possible to grant a recipient Editor rights only for a specific document within an envelope.